Is an HVAC Muffler/Silencer on Direct Vent Water Heater safe or appropriate?
I have a direct vent hot water heater and it makes a good amount of noise near it and also to the upper levels since it is in an unfinished room in the basement and the floor trusses above allow for a lot of vibration. From my research, the noise is actually from the vibrations in the pipe. There are already a few elbows in the way the PVC is run.
I have seen some DIY videos on YouTube where they make a silencer by wrapping some material around a smaller tube and shove inside at the end, but this looks hacky and if you use something like insulation it will be a mold magnet.
I considered purchasing some type of mass loaded vinyl (MLV) pipe wrap type product designed to add mass, but I am concerned about the weight and only about 6 feet of the pipe is available before it disappears into a finished part of the basement on its way outside.
I researched to see if there are off the shelf silencers (sound attenuators, mufflers) that are properly designed for this purpose. I found a few "HVAC" silencers which say they are for duct work, dryer vents, and one that even said it was appropriate for a kitchen cook top fan, but I am not seeing anything directly talking about for use with a water heater. My thought was perhaps they don't work in this situation or it is not safe for use with the direct vent water heater? Perhaps the main audience is really only commercial uses?
Is anyone aware of what type of solutions do work or are appropriate? My thought would be a muffler/silencer/attenuator on the inside would be more effective at quieting. I would just need to fit it to the pipe and remove the PVC where the device would go (?) Is there an issue going from PVC to metal back to PVC?
The MLV is clearly easier to install. I'm concerned that it won't do much since I can only get to about 1/4 of the pipe run, as well as weight pulling down. Is the MLV worth it on a short run and will it add to much weight (pull off the supports from the ceiling or something?)
Things I've found that seems to be purpose built and designed to be safe/appropriate:

ROUND DUCT NOISE MUFFLER SILENCER


Fantech LD Silencers



Other seem to just be foam on the inside of PVC which concerns me for mold, etc.

No one here is likely to suggest or approve anything that violates the manufacturer's requirements. That would invite moral and legal liability for any disasters that occur as a result. We're talking about combustion inside your home, after all.

That said, I think your approach is wrong. You don't want to reduce sound. You want to reduce movement. Stabilize the pipe or isolate it from the framing.

@isherwood - yes, that is the question, is this not-safe or just not common? e.g. I see these systems for exhausting radon, which is why I would be surprised there is nothing for venting the water cooler since that is also unsafe gases (?)

Radon systems just move air. You're talking about fire exhaust in this case, which changes everything, especially when it's traveling through plastic.

@isherwood thanks - I see these being referend for furnaces as well, those are also fire exhaust or a different case as well?

You'd have to be more specific. Some furnaces vent through steel flues. Some use plastic like your water heater.
